# Sequence diagram, having hard time to understand how to interperet question

Tags: digital-logic, sequential-logic

I have to construct a sequential circuit:

We have input x0 and x1

If the following sequence is done, then we want to open a lock, represented by lighting up an LED:

1. x0 = 0, x1 = 0
2. x0 = 1, x1 = 0
3. x0 = 1, x1 = 1

The lock shall remain open until we get x0 = 0 and x1 = 0 again, where we will return to the starting stage and new tries to open it can be made again.

We also have an async reset that will make it so that we return to the starting stage and the whole sequence will have to be done again.

I made the following 2 sequence diagrams, I am leaning more towards the second one being correct because of the async reset, right? Because the async reset only resets the D flip flops and not the input, if we were to reset when we currently have x0= 1, x1 = 0, then we would get problems if we were to use the solution in the first diagram, right?

The circuit is supposed to be a Moore circuit.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without explicitly telling you the answer, let me add some annotations to your two diagrams:

[image]

Does this help answer your question about whether #1 or #2 is the Moore machine?

Also, are you asking for help in determining the final circuit? Or just which diagram is the right one?